# Is there a way to get value example from database, that can be inserted to the column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on tool, that will replace values in specified columns with some other values. User specifies needed table columns in config and the tool replaces their values. I can get the type of a column from information.schema. Is there a way to get a valid value for this column? Or I need to specify them by myself for each column type?

Comment: a valid value meaning what

Comment: I mean value, that will not cause an error when inserting. For example datetime type has specific format.

Comment: well you can use your imagination for overflow and truncate types

Comment: So the user says "order_date" and you fill the whole table with random order dates (say 1975-01-05, 2015-12-24, 2030-01-01, etc.)? The user says "order amount" and you fill the table with random integer order amounts (e.g. -25, 200, 123456789, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, I want to secure data so I just use some non-real values. I will have a problem with unique index, but It will be later.